# Finding the n number in a number

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given equation: $T_n = t_1 \cdot q^{n-1}$

The equation goes like this (some random values I put):

$$435 \cdot 2^{n-1}$$

How can you find the $n$ number if it's squared (or whatever you call this in english)? I have tried many ways, but no luck, it's not like finding a simple X variable.

Note, this is not homework, but for myself to understand.

If anyone can explain it, thanks!

Comment: do you mean $2^n-1$ or $2^{n-1}$?

Comment: Your $\;T_n=T_1q^{n-1}\;$ is the equation for the general term in a geometric sequence. The rest of your question is not comprehensible to me.

Comment: @naslundx, how do you know the OP meant $\;2^n-1\;$ and *not* $\;2^{n-1}\;$ ?? Lucky guess or what?

Comment: @DonAntonio it's the second one, n - 1

Comment: Is your problem finding n, given $T_n$? For example finding n when $435 \cdot 2^n-1=3479$?

Comment: @DonAntonio I simply rendered what was already written in MathJax. Now that we have confirmation on which is correct, I have edited it to fit this.

Comment: Then you better render nothing if you're not sure, @naslundx, and wait until the OP addresses the doubt. Anyone with some time in this site knows that newbies can be extremely sloppy and careless about the way they write mathematics, and your editing the question may confuse others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by any luck you meant to find the value of $\;n\;$ in

$$T=T_1q^{n-1}\implies q^{n-1}=\frac T{T_1}\implies (n-1)\log q=\log\frac T{T_1}\implies$$

$$n=\frac{\log\frac T{T_1}}{\log q}+1$$

Comment: What is the value of T? Would be very nice if you can initialize in when lets say T1 = 377 and q = 6, So i have an example in numbers

Comment: @Jonn you want to find the value of $T$? And you know $T_1$ and $q$?

Comment: I know T, but I dont understand the differnece between T and T1

Comment: In my post's case, T1 = 435 and q = 2. so in his example q^n-1 = 435/435 whcih is (n -1) log q?

Comment: @Jonn okay. $T_n=t_1\cdot q^{n}-1$. If you have $q=2$, $t_1=3$, $n=5$, then $2^5=32$, multiplying by $t$ we get $96$, therefore $T=96-1=95$. We get T by multiplying t by $q^n$ and subtract 1

Comment: Well, just substitute @Jonn...what's your academic level? High school, college...?

Comment: @DonAntonio Highschool

Comment: Simple substitution, @Jonn: $$T_1=435\,,\,q=2\implies n=\frac{\log \frac T{435}}{\log 2}+1$$ and $\;T\;$ is whatever you want this to be equal to: $$T=435\cdot 2^{n-1}$$